# How to find my administrator details when I can't even see an administrator account

Tags: administrator

I have Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. In the beginning, the first user account I created was considered as my administrator account. I changed that account to Standard now and I can't make it back to administrator and whenever I make some changes in my computer, it is asking me for a administrator password which I don't have now.

Comment: I am also getting the same warning when I am trying to use sudo. @muru

Comment: Actually in your specific case, and if you do not have any specific reasons for sticking to an old unsupported release (13.10), I'd recommend an upgrade to a newer release (e.g. 14.04) which will be more of a re-install rather than a distribution upgrade anyway. Take care to not overwrite your HOME directory (do not format the partition it is on). Create another additional emergency admin user account on installing, then re-create your old user account which should automatically point to your old HOME in case you gave it the identical name (if not you could change this later too).

Answer (score 2):

You should login as root user and add grant you sudo rights (edit /etc/sudoers). If you don't know root password, so just reset it by login into single mode (add `single` or `init=/bin/bash` to kernel line at grub menu (during boot)), then you will boot to root cli and can reset root password with `passwd` command.